# How do I stop a macOS download?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I was on the App Store, and accidentally started downloading macOS Sierra. I have no desire to download this, so I want to cancel the download, but I can't figure out how.

From what I have searched, you should go to the purchased section of the App Store, and cancel the download, but macOS doesn't show there:

[image]

What should I do?

The answers to [Can I cancel a download of a Mac Store app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15207/can-i-cancel-a-download-of-a-mac-store-app) do not help me because:

1. The `~/Library/Application Support/AppStore` folder does not exist.
2. Holding the <kbd>alt</kbd> key and clicking the 'x' button does nothing.
3. Running `defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true` does nothing.

Comment: This answer didn't work either?  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/266095/how-to-stop-mac-app-store-from-downloading-macos-sierra?rq=1

Comment: @Allan. No, none of those solutions work.

Comment: Maybe you should just let the download finish and then cancel the installation and delete the downloaded file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the download finish. After it's downloaded the Install macOS Sierra app will launch. You can simply Quit the app as you normally would any app.

If you also want to remove the downloaded file, by default it'll be in your Applications folder (not your Downloads folder). Depending on your setup it may be in your root Applications folder rather than your User's Applications folder.